# aws lambda on .net 6 gives - Error parsing JSON file for appsettings

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-6.0, appsettings

I just created a simple aws lambda function on .net 6. I have added an appsettings.json file and I'm trying to read contents from the file(which have aws resources and later be applied to AWSOptions).

Im unable to read this json file and it shows this error on the console

```
Loaded local Lambda runtime from project output D:\xxx\yyy\zzz\bin\Debug\net6.0
Error parsing JSON file: D:\xxx\yyy\zzz\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.json
Error parsing JSON file: D:\xxx\yyy\zzz\appsettings.json
```

and there isn't much help around on how to read data from config file.

Typical assumption was to load the settings file based on the env that it belonged to and all I get to see it it has changed a little, coming from .netcore2_1 to .net6. Please share your opinion and thanks!

Comment: Can you please add some code and sample files?